# ShellScript:dialog inputbox

Tags: linux, command-line, shell-script, xterm

Somehow to interact with user using shell in Linux you can use `dialog`.
my question about `dialog --inputbox` where you let user to enter a string as an answer to a question then you can redirect the result to `/tmp/input.$$` and you can save it as following:
`dialog --inputbox "Enter you first name:"10 40 2>/tmp/input.$$`

```
x=`cat /tmp/input.$$`
```

Till now that's great !,but what if I write a script so I have to assign "dialog ...." to `xterm` which will open when user click on script file.
The main problem if I did assigning I'll find nothing in `/tmp/input.$$`

The code now :

```
xterm -e dialog --inputbox "Enter your first name" 10 40 2>/tmp/input.$$
x=`cat /tmp/input.$$`
```

then how can I save the value user entered in a variable to use it later ?
Any idea ? even if with different method !
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use quoting to get the redirection to happen in the right place; as written, the output of the `xterm` itself (which is probably empty) is being redirected.  You also need to specify a shell, since `xterm -e` will otherwise `exec` the command directly; redirection requires the shell.

```
xterm -e sh -c 'dialog --inputbox "Enter your first name" 10 40 2>/tmp/input.'$$
x=`cat /tmp/input.$$`
```

You may want to consider using something like `zenity` or `kdialog` instead of `dialog`, in order to avoid the extra `xterm`.

(And in `bash` the second line is better written as `x=$(< /tmp/input.$$)`.)

Comment: Great Mr.geekosaur !...but it shows me an error here it is:"cat: /tmp/input.7562: No such file or directory
" why ?

Comment: It's it...Solved ! sorry, but I thought you've made a mistake to write a single quote before $$ not after !,sorry again

Comment: *sigh* What you're trying to do is difficult (really, I'm serious about using `zenity` instead) because of needing to force stuff through the extra `xterm`; any problems with the command etc. are going to be lost when the `xterm` goes away.  (Maybe try adding `-hold`.)  Look in `/tmp` to see if you have some other `/tmp/input.*` files sitting around, is all I can think of.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I wondered if I should comment on that; it is somewhat tricky.

Comment: I'll try to use `zenity` as soon as I read about it :),thnx